# How add lottie animation on background streamlit app?

Tags: python, css, streamlit, lottie

I have streamlit app and i need add lottie amination on this background. Animation - it is json file on my page.

Some code for open json file as lottie images:

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie

@st.cache
def load_image_json(path):

    """ Load animation and images from json """

    with open(path, 'r') as j:
        animation = json.loads(j.read())
        return animation
        
back_image = load_image_json('image/background_gradient.json')
```

I try this, but is dont work:

```
page_bg_img = '''
<style>
body {
background-image: {st_lottie(back_image, key='back')};
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
'''

st.markdown(page_bg_img, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

UPD. I try next code, no error, but the background animation doesn't load, everything just stays the same as it was before:

```
def load_lottie_url(url: str) -> dict:
    r = requests.get(url)
    return json.loads(r.content)

def set_background_lottie(json_data):
    json_str = json.dumps(json_data)

    tag = f"""<style>.stApp {{background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,{json_str}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: contain; height: 100vh;}}</style>"""

    st.write(tag, unsafe_allow_html=True)

json_data = load_lottie_url("https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_xsrma5om.json")

set_background_lottie(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example usage code snippet?

```
import time
import requests

import streamlit as st
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie_spinner


def load_lottieurl(url: str):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        return None
    return r.json()


lottie_url_hello = "https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_V9t630.json"
lottie_url_download = "https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/private_files/lf30_t26law.json"
lottie_hello = load_lottieurl(lottie_url_hello)
lottie_download = load_lottieurl(lottie_url_download)


st_lottie(lottie_hello, key="hello")

if st.button("Download"):
    with st_lottie_spinner(lottie_download, key="download"):
        time.sleep(5)
    st.balloons()
```